# Launch with parameter +connect_lobby

Tags: rocket-league

I was invited to play Rocket League, but it shows a warning:

[image: Screenshot]

What does that mean? Is it safe to accept the invitation? What will happen?

It happens only for one person. All others work fine.

Comment: Had this message also, I accepted but I don't remember what happened :D